# Angular 5 binding select/options with materialize css

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, materialize

I am currently working on a project using Angular 5 and the framework materialize css and i'm facing an issue with the select/options. I have looked at other posts and I tried many solutions but it's still not working.

What I have so far is I can display data on the select list but I can't bind any objects with it.

This is my **component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SectorService } from '../../../services/sector.service';
import { ProjectService } from '../../../services/project.service';
import { Sector } from '../../../models/sector';
import { Project } from '../../../models/project';
import { toast } from 'angular2-materialize';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-NewProject',
    templateUrl: './NewProject.component.html',
    providers: [SectorService, ProjectService]
})
export class NewProjectComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    sectors: Sector[] = [];
    newProject = new Project();

    types = [{ value: 1, name: 'MS Access' }, { value: 2, name: 'Java' }, { 
value: 3, name: 'C#' }];
    risks = [{ value: 1, name: 'Low' }, { value: 2, name: 'Medium' }, { 
value: 3, name: 'High' }];

    constructor(private _serviceSector: SectorService,                
                private _serviceProject: ProjectService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._serviceSector.GetAll().subscribe(sector => {
            this.sectors = sector;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('select').material_select();
            }, 200);
        });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        /*$(document).ready(function () {
            $('select').material_select();
        });*/
    }

    public Submit(project) {
        console.log(this.newProject);
        toast('new project added !', 4000, 'rounded');
        //this._serviceProject.CreateProject(project).subscribe();
    }

}
```

This is my **html** I'm just showing you the selects

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select [(ngModel)]="newProject.type" name="types" id="types">
                <option *ngFor="let type of types" [ngValue]="type.name">{{type.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <label for="types">Technologies</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <select [(ngModel)]="newProject.idSector" name="sectors" id="sectors" aria-required="true">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your sector</option>
                <option *ngFor="let sector of sectors" id="group_{{sector.id}}" [ngValue]="sector.id"> {{sector.name}} </option>
            </select>
            <label for="sectors">Sector</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also have 2 classes called Project and Sector with their attributes.

I added a timeout to initialize the materialize select just to be sure.

I am still working on it I will give updates if I find any solutions.

Thank you in advance for your time !

Comment: Can you provide a plunker so we can take a better look at it.
Also btw, have you tried https://material.angular.io/
It's better and easier and designed specifically for Angular 5.

Comment: Do you try to pass `type.value` in `ngValue` of your `types` dropdown instead of `type.name` ?

Comment: It works using the class 'browser-default' on the select tag. @Dani-ProjectGamma I'll provide a plunker as soon as possible and I already did a lot using the materialize css framework I don't want to loose time rewriting views. I only encountered a problem using select/options.

Answer (score 1):

in angular 9: i just added a hack below code in ngAfterViewInit() reason is select initialized before it actually process all options

```html
setTimeout(() => {
      $('select').formSelect();
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the *.component.ts file.
I am using Angular 8 and this worked fine for me it's a quick workaround for the model binding, you can bind the value to the model inside the submit function.
I have used the map function because if you use multiple select the getinstance() will return a array.
Hope this helps you!!

```
import * as M from 'materialize-css';

export class ComponentName implements AfterViewInit {
 instance;

 ngAfterViewInit(){
     // initializing Selcet 
     this.instance = M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelector('select'));  
 }

  onSubmit(){
    //returns an array in case of multiple select
    this.instance.getSelectedValues().map((elem) =>{
    console.log(elem)
  })
 } 
}
```